# VueJS Validation: Clicking "add" button leads field to get a value

Tags: javascript, validation, vue.js

)

I got a question about validation of forms.

This is my form:

```
<form class = "uk-form-row" v-validator="formTax"@submit.prevent = "add | valid">
    <div class="uk-grid">
        <div class="uk-width-1-4">
            <select class = "uk-form-small" name="countrycode" v-model = "newTax.countrycode" v-validate:required>
                <option v-for = "country in countries" value = "{{ $key }}" :disabled = "vatMatch($key)">
                    {{country}}
                </option>
            </select>    
            <p class="uk-form-help-block uk-text-danger" v-show="formTax.countrycode.invalid">{{ 'Field cannot be blank.' | trans }}</p>        
        </div>

        <div class="uk-width-1-4">
            <input class = "uk-input-large" type = "number"
                   placeholder = "{{ 'Companies' | trans }}" name="companies" v-model = "newTax.companies" number v-validate:required>
                   <p class="uk-form-help-block uk-text-danger" v-show="formTax.companies.invalid">{{ 'Field cannot be blank.' | trans }}</p>

        </div>
        <div class="uk-width-1-4">
            <input class = "uk-input-large" type = "number"
                   placeholder = "{{ 'Individuals' | trans }}" name="individuals" v-model = "newTax.individuals"
                   number v-validate:required>
                   <p class="uk-form-help-block uk-text-danger" v-show="formTax.individuals.invalid">{{ 'Field cannot be blank.' | trans }}</p>

        </div>     
        <div class="uk-width-1-4">           
            <span class = "uk-align-right"> <button class = "uk-button" @click = "add | valid">{{ 'Add' | trans }}</button></span>            
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is the Vue-Source:

```
$(function () {

    var vm = new Vue({

        el: '#settings',

        data: {
            config: $data.config,
            roles: $data.roles,
            countries: $data.countries,

            newTax: {
                countrycode: '',
                companies: '',
                individuals: ''
            }
        },

        methods: {

            add: function (e) {

                e.preventDefault();

                if (!this.newTax) return;

                this.config.vat.push({
                    countrycode: this.newTax.countrycode,
                    companies: this.newTax.companies,
                    individuals: this.newTax.individuals,
                });

                this.newTax = '';
            },

            remove: function (vat) {
                this.config.vat.$remove(vat);
            },

            save: function () {
                console.log(this.config.vat);

                this.$http.post('admin/app/save', {entries: this.config}, function () {
                        this.$notify('Settings saved.');
                    }, function (data) {
                        this.$notify(data, 'danger');
                    }
                );
            },

            vatMatch: function (code) {
                return this.config.vat.filter(function (vat) {
                        return vat.countrycode == code;
                    }).length > 0;
            }

        }

    });

});
```

This already works fine - but if I choose a country and leave the taxes-fields empty and click "add" again, the first field gets filled with "0" and after a second click the second field gets filled with "0" and the add-button works. Why is the validation-rule setting "0" if validation fails?
I created a little gif to demonstrate what I mean: http://d.pr/eRbM

Comment: Please post your Vue / javascript code.

Comment: I added the vue-sourcecode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your add method. When you validate the `newTax` object with `if (!this.newTax)`, it will return true. Even if the object properties are empty, the object exists. Creating unexpected behavior.

You should validate each property that is required, for example, if you require `countrycode` and `companies`, change your validation to:

```
if (!this.newTax.countrycode || !this.newTax.companies) return;
```

Also, there is a problem when you try reset your `nexTax` object. You need to pass in a clean object, but you are reassigning it with an empty instring.

Try this instead, for your add method:

```
add: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

    if (!this.newTax.countrycode || !this.newTax.companies || !this.newTax.indiduals) return;

     this.config.vat.push({
         countrycode: this.newTax.countrycode,
         companies: this.newTax.companies,
         individuals: this.newTax.individuals,
      );

      this.newTax = {
          contrycode = '',
          companies = '',
          individuals = ''
      };
}
```

Comment: Hm, thank you very much.

I'm using http://d.pr/12saT now, but it does not work, too. Or did I misunderstand what you said?

Comment: Ok. First, keep in mind that `if (!this.newTax.countrycode || !this.newTax.countrycode)` is the same as `if (!this.newTax.countrycode)` , you are duplicating the check. Instead of checking each property at it's own if statement, you can use or `||` to check then all in one statement.

Comment: About the error still happening, where are you getting `$data` from? Please post it.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I corrected the check to `if (!this.newTax || !this.newTax.countrycode || this.newTax.companies || this.newTax.individuals) return;` but without success.

The $data comes from the PHP-controller of Pagekit - see here: http://d.pr/1e74W

Comment: Hi @crabbly,

thanks for your help. Unfortunately the problem still persists.

Comment: I guess I figured out something: I added console.log("Test") to the head of the add-function - but it's never called.

So I guess the function is not called, because something else is preventing it.

Comment: I have no idea how you are using the `$data` variable created in PHP, inside your Javascript code.

Comment: Maybe I did not find the right words. The content of data is passed to the Vue-Instance via PHP (the controller adds some defined values, e.g. predefined values for data.config, data.roles, ...). So what drives me crazy is the fact, that the add-method is not called as it seems, because the `console.log("Test");` I added at the beginning is not writing anything to the error-console of the browser.

Comment: In your add button click event, change to this `@click="add()"`

Comment: Okay, so if I do so, the console.log is written. But the add-action does no longer work, because of `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.preventDefault')`. If I uncomment preventDefault, I always get new entries.

Comment: I think I got it:

`<input>` contains `v-model = "newTax.companies" number v-validate:required`. If I leave out `number` it works without problems. But how can I require a number in another way?

Comment: You could do that with HTML alone, by using input type number. For ex.: `<input type="number" min="1" max="5">`